# Omisión de artículo

Tags: gramática, artículos

¿Por qué cuando aclaramos un sustantivo con adjetivo, en algunos casos omitimos el artículo? Por ejemplo en:

> Necesito agua potable

¿Por qué no es?

> Necesito **un** agua potable

**Amor** también es un sustantivo no contable pero se puede decir **Busco un amor verdadero**.

Answer (score 11):

El hecho de que se añada o no un adjetivo no está directamente relacionado con que se omita el artículo. Si no se especifica ningún adjetivo, el artículo sigue sin ser necesario:

> Necesito agua.

La razón de que se omita el artículo es que "agua" es, como bien has supuesto, incontable. En español, sin embargo, se puede añadir un artículo a un sustantivo  incontable para hacerlo contable mediante metonimia:

> Necesito *un* agua = Necesito una botella de agua, un vaso de agua, etc.

¿Por qué no suena bien usar un artículo con "agua potable"? Sencillamente porque las expresiones "necesito una botella de agua potable" o "necesito un vaso de agua potable" no son lo suficientemente comunes como para justificar la metonimia: si el agua está embotellada o en un vaso, lo más probable es que sea potable. En cualquier caso, "un agua potable" referido a "una botella/un vaso de agua potable" no es incorrecto, solo inusual.

En el caso de "amor verdadero" se usa un artículo porque en español "amor", a diferencia de en otros idiomas, no es un sustantivo incontable en todos los casos. Por ejemplo:

> ¿*Cuántos* amores verdaderos has tenido en tu vida?
>
> No todos han tenido *un* amor verdadero.

En este caso, "amor verdadero" es un sustantivo contable porque se lo equipara con "persona con la que se mantiene una relación de amor verdadero". En otros casos, no tiene por qué serlo:

> Busco amor verdadero.

Resulta interesante observar cómo cambia el significado de la oración anterior si se añade un artículo:

> Busco un amor verdadero.

En el primer caso, la persona dice que busca amor verdadero como algo incontable. En el segundo, está diciendo que busca una relación amorosa verdadera.

También se lo puede considerar una contracción de *un tipo de amor*:

> Busco un amor verdadero = Busco *un tipo de* amor que sea verdadero.